# using combine class with revtex4-1 - command \published already defined

Tags: incompatibility, revtex, combine

I'm trying to combine (with `combine` class) many (about 100) TeX files to prepare a book of abstracts for a conference. They are written using `revtex4-1` class. When I use this classes together

```
\documentclass[11pt,colclass=revtex4-1]{combine}
\title{Book of abstracts}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents % main ToC
\clearpage

\section{Editor's introduction} 
bla bla bla

%\begin{papers} % start of individual articles/papers
%\coltoctitle{1st article} % first article title into main ToC
%\coltocauthor{A.~N.~Author} % first authors into main ToC
%\label{art1}
%\import{art1} % first article, may have own ToC,
%\end{papers} 

\clearpage
\end{document}
```

I get this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \published already defined.
```

What can I do to fix this problem? I understand, that both in `revtex4-1.cls` and `combine.cls` the `\published` command is defined. In `combine.cls` with the use of `\renewcommand`, in `revtex4-1.cls` with `\newcommand` (I changed it to `\renewcommand` but it didn't help).

Comment: Since you're willing to edit `revtex4-1.cls` simply comment out the  definition of `\published`.

Answer (score 1):

You mention that changing the `\newcommand{\published}...` in the `revtex-1` class to `\renewcommand...` "doesn't help.". Two suggestions: (i) be sure to delete all aux files before recompiling and (ii) if that doesn't help, try a `\providecommand` statement for `\published`. Finally, are you sure that `\published` is not defined in a third instance somewhere?

Comment: I deleted all aux files. I tried \providecommand, I put it instead of \newcommand or \renewcommand in revtex and combine sty and cls files. I refreshed FNDB od MiKTeX. And nothing helps... In the example I gave there are no more instances (and it doesn't compile).

Answer (score 1):

define an own wrapper class `my-revtex.cls` which sets the `\published` to undefined.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{my-revtex.cls}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{revtex4-1}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{revtex4-1}
\let\Published\published% save the one from revtex
\let\published\relax
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[11pt,colclass=my-revtex]{combine}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{Book of abstracts}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents % main ToC
\clearpage

\section{Editor's introduction} 
bla bla bla

\begin{papers} % start of individual articles/papers
\coltoctitle{1st article} % first article title into main ToC
\coltocauthor{A.~N.~Author} % first authors into main ToC
\label{art1}
%\import{art1} % first article, may have own ToC,
\end{papers} 

\clearpage
\end{document}
```